# Why Pycharm linter complains about text files?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have some code written in a `.txt` file. Upon openning it, the linter fills the screen with red bars and error. What language is it expecting?

[image]

The image shows one error pop-up when I hover over one of the red lines.

Comment: Have you checked your indentation?

Comment: @snoopstick There is nothing wrong about the code, it runs smoothly on a .py file. I'm just wondering why all this mess why I save the code in a text file.

Comment: That's probably because PyCharm always points out 'not-real' English words

Comment: @snoopstick I'm putting your answer in a text file, still shows same errors.

Comment: Well then I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `HyperParam.txt` isn't assigned to a text file type but to something else - note the file icon with a small gear. Check **Settings | Editor | File Types** -> find the type with the same icon and remove `HyperParam.txt` or `*.txt` from "Registered patterns" for it.